# Get GUID from an installed Application c#

Tags: c#, winforms, guid

I am doing a winform application that need to uninstall another Winform application that is installed by installshield. I have searched the correct way to unistall it is

> Process.Start("msiexec /x {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}");
>   where xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx represents GUID of that application that you want to uninstall.

But I do not how can I find the `GUID` from an application called  `text.exe`

I have found

> var assembly = typeof(Program).Assembly;
>   var attribute = (GuidAttribute)assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), true)[0];
>               var id = attribute.Value;

but this retrieves the `GUID` from the current Application.

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to find it in the registry. And note, I would do this manually and add the GUID you find to your program rather than try to programmatically find it from the executable name. The chance of a collisions with executable names is too great.

Answer (score 3):

That GUID is the GUID associated with the installer (more accurately known as a [Package Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), you'll be able to pull these from HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, I am not familiar with the ability to pull this directly from the application.

*Edit Alternatively if you have access to the WiX script (should you be using WiX to generate the MSI) it should be the Id attribute of the [Product](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/product.html) Element. You may also be able to use a tool such as Orca to check this property of an MSI that has already been created.

Comment: You might also check the `Wow6432Node` as well if it's a 32-bit program on a 64-bit OS. So `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`